# Implementing Credit Card Payment Method using PayPal API in Virtuemart

Tags: api, paypal, virtuemart

We are running Virtuemart 2.0.14 in Joomla 2.5.8 environment. Trying to set up Paypal Payments Pro in Virtuemart interface. Where do I go in PayPal Manager to find/create DoDirectPayment API credentials? Need API so user stays on existing website when putting in credit card, without being forwarded to PayPal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Manager uses the PayFlow API which is separate from DoDirectPayment.

Since you're using PayPal Manager, you may or may not have access to DoDirectPayment.  If you want to try it, you can get your credentials by [logging into this tool with your PayPal account](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run).  You could also find them from within your PayPal account profile under Request API Credentials, but that tool will be much quicker.

If you set it up that way, though, and you get an error about authentication, that means your PayPal account is configured in a way that forces you to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment.  In this case, you'll need to check to make sure VirtuMart supports PayFlow.

It all gets a little confusing because PayFlow and Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment) used to be separate products within PayPal.  They technically still are, however, they're calling both of them Payments Pro now, but depending on what version you're on you might have access to only DoDirectPayment, or you might have access to only PayFlow, or you might have access to both.

You'll just have to try one or the other, and if that doesn't work, switch to the one you didn't try.